# What major or well-known script-writing competitions exist for anime works?

Tags: anime-production

I'm familar with the Animeka anime script-writing competition, but it doesn't seem like there are many others out there. What major or well-known script-writing competitions exist for anime works?

Thanks

Comment: The only other one I can think of, in the same catergory, is the [Kyoto Animation Prize](http://www.kyotoanimation.co.jp/kyoani_award/). You can see a list of other competitions in other literary and arts categories [here](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2133413293346698001).

Comment: BTW, we opened up a [meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/743/49) on whether to keep this question closed or not.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be three main anime script awards, at least in Japan.

**[Tokyo Anime Award](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Anime_Award)** includes a wide variety of anime and categories, including two for screenplays. One is for screenplays and one is for original adaptation screenplays. These seem to be all professional/aired screenwriters/anime. These categories were created in 2014, though the Award is from 2002.

**[Animax Taishō](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animax_Taish%C5%8D)** is for submitted rather than already aired anime, and the winners are produced and aired on Animax. It's not clear if this has been run after 2008.

**[Kyoto Animation Awards](http://www.kyotoanimation.co.jp/kyoani_award/outline/)** is also for unpublished work, though oddly they seem to not have winners every year. In the last cycle, for example, there were no winners. This is run by Kyoto Animation.